# How to point root / to subdirectory in nginx

Tags: nginx

Currently I have my webroot on http://example.com pointing to the `/var/www/example.com/`

I want to move the WP installation from there to sub folder (i.e. `/var/www/example.com/int/`) and point the webroot to the sub folder, so that the website urls preserve the same.

This is my server configuration, but it's not working. Can you please advice?

```
server {

    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(woff|eot|ttf|svg|mp4|webm|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|otf)$ {
            expires 1d;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log        off;
    }

    location / {
           root /var/www/example.com/int;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working means what?

Comment: @davidbaumann Means that it doesn't redirect to the sub folder index.php but to 404 Not Found

Comment: You have two `root` statements, is there a reason for this? Where is your PHP configuration?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, i have more sub folders (uk, us, it etc) each containing WP installation. That's why i have one main web root and then i have sub folders.